# ATOM/PlatformIO OpenOCD init failed

Tags: atom-editor, openocd, platformio

I'm trying to upload to a board for my 3d printer and was following a couple of online tutorials; however, when I'm trying to upload to the board I receive the error below.

I'm running an up-to-date version of Windows 10, Atom & PlatformIO, the board is an SKR E3 Dip (https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-E3-DIP-V1.0).

I have tried

1. plugging the board into multiple USB ports, because looking online it seemed that there was a problem with USB3
2. updating drivers

Any advice on additional troubleshooting?

```
Processing STM32F103RE_bigtree_USB (platform: ststm32; board: genericSTM32F103RE; framework: arduino)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/ststm32/genericSTM32F103RE.html
PLATFORM: ST STM32 6.0.0 > STM32F103RE (64k RAM. 512k Flash)
HARDWARE: STM32F103RET6 72MHz, 64KB RAM, 512KB Flash
DEBUG: Current (stlink) External (blackmagic, jlink, stlink)

PACKAGES: toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi 1.70201.0 (7.2.1), framework-arduinoststm32-maple 1.10000.190819 (1.0.0), tool-stm32duino 1.0.2, tool-openocd 2.1000.190707 (10.0), tool-dfuutil 1.9.190708
Converting Marlin.ino
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/librarymanager/ldf.html
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 39 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
Dependency Graph
|-- <U8glib-HAL> 0.4.1
|   |-- <Wire> 1.0
|-- <LiquidCrystal> 1.3.4
|   |-- <Wire> 1.0
|-- <TMCStepper> 0.6.2
|   |-- <SoftwareSerialM>
|-- <Adafruit MAX31865 library> 1.0.3
|-- <LiquidTWI2>
|   |-- <Wire> 1.0
|-- <Arduino-L6470> 0.7.0
|-- <SailfishLCD>
|-- <SailfishRGB_LED>
|   |-- <Wire> 1.0
|-- <SlowSoftI2CMaster>
|-- <SoftwareSerialM>
|-- <STM32ADC> 1.0
|-- <USBComposite for STM32F1> 0.91
|-- <EEPROM>
|-- <Wire> 1.0
Building in release mode
Checking size .pio\build\STM32F103RE_bigtree_USB\firmware.elf
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
DATA:    [===       ]  25.4% (used 16664 bytes from 65536 bytes)
PROGRAM: [====      ]  38.9% (used 203700 bytes from 524288 bytes)
Configuring upload protocol...
AVAILABLE: blackmagic, dfu, jlink, serial, stlink
CURRENT: upload_protocol = stlink
Uploading .pio\build\STM32F103RE_bigtree_USB\firmware.elf
xPack OpenOCD, 64-bit Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev (2019-07-17-11:28)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 1


hla_swd
Error: open failed
in procedure 'program'
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked

*** [upload] Error 1
```

Comment: How have you connected the board to the computer? The configuration you are using wants to use an ST-Link debug probe.

Comment: A mini USB cable (Mini USB Cable USB 2.0 Type A to Mini B Cable)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which software you are building and what online tutorial you are following. But my understanding of the board is that you build the firmware, then copy the firmware (`.pio\build\STM32F103RE_bigtree_USB\firmware.bin` to the SD card and start you printer with the SD card. The current build is configured for ST-Link upload, which would require an ST-Link debug probe attached to the connector in the center of your board. An alternative to try is `upload_protocol = dfu`.